# I can't install valgrind due dpkg-deb broken pipe, how to fix this?

Tags: apt, dpkg, locale, pipe

```
hanu@hanu-HP-Pavilion-Sleekbook-14:~/raijin/build_debug$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  locales
The following packages will be upgraded:
  locales
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1008 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,801 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,537 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  locales
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 204496 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace locales 2.13+git20120306-9 (using .../locales_2.17-92_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement locales ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.17-92_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/validlocale', which is also in package libc-bin 2.17-0ubuntu5
configured to not write apport reports
                                      dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.17-92_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


hanu@hanu-HP-Pavilion-Sleekbook-14:~/raijin/build_debug$ valgrind
The program 'valgrind' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install valgrind
```

Comment: @guntbert his problem is that two packages are trying to provide the same file, he either have to delete `libc-bin` (**which is a very bad idea**) or remove `locales` from the installation, and Jokerdino's answer fit both solutions. Trough, truth be told, I think OP is mixing several repositories.

Answer (score 0):

When finding errors, it is usually informative to look at the *first* error, the one that caused the later ones.

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.17-92_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/validlocale', which is also in package libc-bin 2.17-0ubuntu5
```

The problem is as dpkg says: the same file `validlocale` exists in two packages, so they cannot both be installed.  What might fix this is to upgrade the *other* package first.

```
aptitude install libc-bin
```

When that is finished, try installing valgrind again.

Answer (score -1):

It may be better to install it from the Ubuntu Software Center. Search for **valgrind**

[image: Ubuntu Software Center]

This would allow you to install the main programme

[image]

and any other additional packages which may be relevant.

[image]

Comment: The problem will persist if the dpkg error isn't fixed.

Comment: @Braiam That sounds like a good place to start an answer :)

Comment: Check the duplicated, the answer is there.